# split a string Java (At certain character)

Tags: java

I'm trying to split a string after character 266 for instance. The user enters a string, and if its over a certain length, spit it at the (in my case) 266th char.
Here is my code:

```
if(inputText.length() > 266){
        //Max Chars Reached. Move Some To Part 2

}
```

So, what I need is that it takes the 267th and on and sets that to a var(p2 for instance) and rest to p1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `substring()` to split strings at specific indexes:

```
if(inputText.length() > 266){
        String var1 = inputText.substring(0, 267);
        String var2 = inputText.substring(267);
}
```

More information for Strings can be found in [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)).

Comment: Glad to know! Would you please accept or upvote answers that you found useful?

Comment: Can click tick for 3 mins yet XD I will after that!

Answer (score 3):

Use `String.substring()` as descriped in the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-). This allows to split a String beginning with a certain index or from an start index till an end index. See this simple example:

```
    public static void main(String []args){
        String myString = "Hallo";
        String part1 = myString.substring(0,2);
        String part2 = myString.substring(2);

        System.out.println(part1); //Ha
        System.out.println(part2); //llo
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String p1 = InputText.substring(0, 266);String p2 = InputText.substring(266);
```

Comment: You should explain your solution to make it easier to understand (also putting it into one line doesn't help reading it).

Answer (score 0):

```
String splited = inputText.substring(index);

// in your case
String splited = inputText.substring(266);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a loop, sth like this:

```
String s="......"; //your long string
while (s.length()>266) {
   System.out.println(s.substring(0,266)); //process substring
   s=s.substring(266);  // reloop the rest
}
System.out.println(s); // process last chunk
```